# why Combination keys does not work properly on some systems in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created an application to do some automated function with Visual studio 2012 ultimate in winform.
It works well on my laptop,on my my friend's laptop (both win 7)
even I tried in Win XP virtual machine (on my laptop) it works well!
but when I tried that on a customer PC (real low-end OLD PC) that has a win XP OS it does not work properly!
this is my code:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^{A}");
SendKeys.SendWait("^{v}");
```

when i execute that code on mentioned PC it just type "Av" while it should operate Select All & Paste operation. I thought maybe it's because that PC is slow so i tried a little sleep before them but no success. I thought maybe it's because of operating system that it's not compatible with win XP, but when i tried on my virtual machine it worked properly!
what's wrong?

Comment: As an alternative you can try to clear the destination TextBox (or whatever it is), then write the content of the clipboard in it.

Comment: even when input box is empty it does not work properly!
is there  any other way to paste the content of clipboard?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42859/Set-and-Get-Text-in-the-Clipboard

Comment: Rather than using the clipboard as a transfer medium, have you considered using [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.90).aspx) instead? It's how assistive tools/technologies interact with other programs, it's supported in .NET 3.5 (and back to XP) and despite being a managed library, doesn't require that the *target* application be using any particular technology.

Comment: is it just for WPF?
and my question is why that code does not work properly on that PC!?